# Trouble using ogr2ogr -sql commands from QGIS to rename attribute fields

Tags: qgis, sql, ogr2ogr

I have a large number of files whose attribute fields are named consistently, but incorrectly. I would ordinarily use ogr2ogr.exe to fix this from the command line using something like:

```
ogr2ogr "C:\Temp1\OutDataSet.shp" "C:\Temp1\asdf\InDataSet.shp" -sql "SELECT End AS LineEnd, begin AS Begin FROM InDataSet"
```

This creates a new .shp file, renames attribute fields from `End` to `LineEnd` and from `begin` to `Begin` , also drops many unwanted attribute fields from the original shapefile.

I was hoping that I could achieve the same thing from QGIS 2.18 processing toolbox > [OGR] Miscellaneous > Execute SQL, as It is easy to set up a batch by using the QGIS forms. Has anyone had any success with this tool for this task?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: QGIS version 2.18

Comment: worked for me on a single layer and as a batch. are you getting an error or something?

Comment: Yes, it throws up an error for me! neuhausr if you get a sec, please post up a screen grab of your snyntax, maybe I'm doing something stupid! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `ogrinfo` instead of `ogr2ogr` updating the input shapefile without creating a new one:

```
ogrinfo "C:\Temp1\asdf\InDataSet.shp" -sql "ALTER TABLE InDataSet RENAME COLUMN oldcolumnname TO newcolumnname"
```

But `Execute SQL` of the Processing toolbox is based only on `ogr2ogr` command, so it's convenient to execute a loop over your based on `ogrinfo` in the OSGeo4W Shell.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
ogr2ogr "C:\Temp1\OutDataSet.shp" "C:\Temp1\asdf\InDataSet.shp" -sql "SELECT *, End AS LineEnd, begin AS Begin FROM InDataSet"
```